# Finding saved Json files in internal storage

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, gson

I am saving a couple of ArrayLists into the user's internal storage when using my application with the Gson library. Since i didn't find anything about this, i was wondering if there is a way for me to find those saved lists as a file in my android's phone interna storage and see them eg. in a .txt representation?

***Writting to internal storage***

```
public static void Write(ArrayList<Integer> icons, ArrayList<Integer> cardArts, ArrayList<String> cardNameAndDescription,
                         ArrayList<String> leaderSkills, ArrayList<String> superAttackNames, ArrayList<String> superAttackDesc,
                         ArrayList<String> passiveSkillNames, ArrayList<String> passiveSkillDesc, Context context) {

    SharedPreferences appPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appPrefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String iconsJson = gson.toJson(icons);
    String cardArtsJson = gson.toJson(cardArts);
    String cardNameAndDescriptionJson = gson.toJson(cardNameAndDescription);
    String leaderSkillsJson = gson.toJson(leaderSkills);
    String superAttackNamesJson = gson.toJson(superAttackNames);
    String superAttackDescJson = gson.toJson(superAttackDesc);
    String passiveSkillNamesJson = gson.toJson(passiveSkillNames);
    String passiveSkillDescJson = gson.toJson(passiveSkillDesc);
    editor.putString("Icons",iconsJson);
    editor.putString("CardArt",cardArtsJson);
    editor.putString("CardNameAndDesc",cardNameAndDescriptionJson);
    editor.putString("LeaderSkills",leaderSkillsJson);
    editor.putString("SANames",superAttackNamesJson);
    editor.putString("SADescs",superAttackDescJson);
    editor.putString("PassiveSkillNames",passiveSkillNamesJson);
    editor.putString("PassiveSkillDesc",passiveSkillDescJson);
    editor.apply();
    editor.commit();
    Log.d("WriteData","Data written successfully!");
}
```

Comment: Json files are text files. Or not?

Comment: `into the user's internal storage`. What do you consider to be users internal storage? Mention full path please.

Comment: `wondering if there is a way for me to find those saved lists as a file`. Strange formulation. I would think you would ask `wondering if there is a way for me to find those files`.

Comment: @greenapps i haven't specified a path(i believe). I'm updating my post with the saving code so that  you can take a look

Comment: You are writing to shared preferences. You write some key=value strings in an xlm file. That xml file is indeed in private internal memory of your app. An xml file is a text file too.

Comment: alright but how do i find it in my phone's internal storage? how do i find that text file?

Comment: First tell how you wanna find the file. Programmatically? Using a tool or app? Or Android Studio?

Comment: Maybe using a tool? Definitely not programmatically.  For example (if possible) by using the in-built phone's My files app?

Comment: Other apps -like file explorer apps- on your device have no acces to your app's private internal memory.

Comment: @greenapps then how can i see the file? maybe from android studio's file explorer somehow?

Comment: Yes. Maybe. Did you try?

Comment: i tried by doing this -> android -> data -> com.mypackage.something -> then says something about run: .... but has no files in it

Comment: The directory to look for is /data/data/<packagename>/shared_prefs and there is no android in it.

Comment: when i follow this path: i get : run-as: Could not set capabilites

Comment: How far did you come? Did it start with /data? And there was no android mentioned?

Comment: yes /data/data/<mypackage>/ the message above

Comment: You can copy the file to external storage. After that its easy to display the copy.

Comment: you mean like, get it programmatically and then also save it to the  external storage?

Comment: Yes programmatically.

Comment: i haven't specified a name for the xml file that you previously mentioned though so how can i access it if i don't have it's name

Comment: String path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePaht() + "/shared_prefs/" + getPackageName() + "_preferences.xml".